# 2 issues: centering div + CSS animations

Tags: html, css, animation

http://carloshermoso.com/works/rwd/

Hi,

two different questions:

1.- I have issues centering the services. They should be with same margin by left and right side, same as it happens with the rest of the page.

id="webDevelopmentServices" are the 3 services.
class="service" is each of the services.

2.- Why CSS animations are not working fine in Firefox? They aren't working in IE either. In Chrome are all smooth though.

Thanks a million in advance!

Comment: Please post the relevant code as well

Comment: [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: #mainContent #webDevelopmentServices .service { display:inline-block; font-size:15px; line-height:17px; margin:0 2%; width:21%; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
#mainContent #webDevelopmentServices .service {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 17px;
    margin: 0 2%;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 21%;
}
```

removing the "float:left" with a display:inline-block;

in my firefox the animations are working. 
But ofcourse, css animation will not work in earlier IEs, but this is a world wide known problem :)

Comment: Removing the float:left with a display:inline-block worked great for having the services centered, but for some reason now the 1st service is not horizontally aligned with the next 2. Any idea? Also, regarding the animations issue, at my end it will only work in Firefox after the page is refreshed. The 1st time the page loads it will not work properly. Having animations working in at least IE9 would be great, but if not possible, then it's ok (I was hoping that IE9 at least to be honest; don't care that much of IE8/7)

Comment: view my edited answer, where you see that i added the "vertical-align" property.

Comment: Done! Thanks a lot again! BTW, if you can have a look at this? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138114/why-css-animations-are-working-all-smooth-in-chrome-but-not-in-firefox)