# Why CSS animations are working all smooth in Chrome but not in Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, css, firefox

Why CSS animations are working all smooth in Chrome but not in Firefox?

url: http://carloshermoso.com/works/rwd/

```
#mainContent h2 { -moz-animation-duration:3s; -moz-animation-name:slideIn; -webkit-animation-duration:3s; -webkit-animation-name:slideIn; text-transform:uppercase; }
@-moz-keyframes slideIn
{
from { margin-bottom:100%; width:300%; }
to { margin-top:0%; width:100%; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn
{
from { margin-bottom:100%; width:300%; }
to { margin-top:0%; width:100%; }
}
```

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

Probably simply due to the different rendering engines of chrome and firefox. You can take a look at [this](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css) if you want to see how you can improve the css transform speed.
Additionally, your code isn't working in Opera or Internet Explorer because you haven't included the normal (no-prefix) `animation` property that Opera and IE 10 use. Note that IE 9 and Below don't support CSS animations at all. More information on that [here](http://caniuse.com/css-animation).

Comment: mm... it doesn't really seem to be a fix-solution for what I'm facing... I am actually surprised this is not working in Firefox. It doesn't work in Opera or IE all versions either. But at least Firefox was expected.

Comment: Updated my answer to accommodate that

Comment: OK, about not working on IE. But there's must be some changes to my code to make this simply animation work in Firefox. I've seen different animations working really smoothly for Firefox before.