# Animation is smooth in Chrome, but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, d3.js

I'm making a bar graph that looks something like this (does not show the problem): https://jsfiddle.net/8ywf45s1/.

The Problem: In Firefox there's this thing that happens where the bars look like they become "dissociated" from the base line, as opposed to running smoothly like in Chrome.  Additionally, this only seems to happen for some of the bars, and only when moving in certain directions.  Here's a super simplified visual example of what I'm seeing (the problem applies when the bars are stationary like this too): https://jsfiddle.net/qbtbhhmw/1/

I've been trying to do things piece by piece to find out when the problem starts, but have had a hard time recreating it thus far.  It might be related to the animation part (Mandatory code for fiddle posting):

```
d3.select("#bar" + i).transition()
    .duration(aniDuration)
    .ease(aniEase)
    .attr("y", function () {
        if (d >= 0) {
            return newTop - newHeight;
        } else {
            return newBot;
        }
    })
    .attr("height", newHeight);
```

**Additional Details**: Pretty much, some select bar below the base line become dissociated when moving upwards, and similarly some select bars above the base line become dissociated when moving downwards.  The bars that dissociate differ per data set, but they are consistently the same for that specific data set.

I'm not sure this is enough information for anyone to provide help.  The entirely of the project is a bit large, and it reads .csv data to generate the info for the bars so it could take a while to get an example of the problem up and running.  I thought I'd give what I had already a shot here to see if that was avoidable.  Sorry for the amateurishness, I'm new to web development overall.

**Note**: I tried using a potentially related CSS animation solution regarding GPU acceleration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138114/why-css-animations-are-working-all-smooth-in-chrome-but-not-in-firefox), but adding the "translate3d(0,0,0)" in the CSS didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to make it work

Instead of animating individual elements, put a group around all of the things you want to move and transform the group.

For example...

```
<svg width="300" height="400">
    <g  transform="translate(20, 180)> animate this element
        <g class="yGroups" id="yGroup1"">
            <line class="baseLines" id="baseLine1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="260" y2="0"></line>
            <text class="lineLabels" id="lineLabel1" x="-15" y="4.25">0</text>
        </g>
        <rect class="bars" id="cBarTop" x="85" width="40" y="128" height="50"></rect>
        <rect class="bars" id="cBarBot" x="150" width="40" y="182" height="50"></rect>
    </g>
</svg>
```

By the way, you can set multiple attrinutes like this...

```
var cBarTop = svg1.append("rect")
    .attr({
        "class": "bars",
        "id": "cBarTop",
        "x": marginX + width*0.25,
        "width": barWidth,
        "y": height/2 - barHeight - 2,
        "height": barHeight
    });
var fBarTop = svg2.append("rect")
    .attr({
        "class": "bars",
        "id": "fBarTop",
        "x": marginX + width * 0.25,
        "width": barWidth,
        "y": height / 2 - barHeight - 2,
        "height": barHeight
    });
var cBarBot = svg1.append("rect")
    .attr({
        "class": "bars",
        "id": "cBarBot",
        "x": marginX + width / 2,
        "width": barWidth,
        "y": height / 2 + 2,
        "height": barHeight
    });
var fBarBot = svg2.append("rect")
    .attr({
        "class": "bars",
        "id": "fBarBot",
        "x": marginX + width / 2,
        "width": barWidth,
        "y": height / 2 + 2,
        "height": barHeight
    });
```

And a better way to do this...

```
this.getAttribute("y")
```

is this...

```
d3.select(this).attr("y")
```

### How to fix the architecture

Having said all the above, the proper approach is to bind data to the elements, create a declarative rule for updating the layout, then change the data and update.

Here is an example using these techniques and a few others...

```js
/*********************************
   DRAW STUFF
*********************************/
//SET STUFF UP
var chrome = d3.select("#chrome");
var marginX = 20;
var cheight = chrome.node().clientHeight,
    cwidth = chrome.node().clientWidth,
 width = cwidth - marginX*2,
 height = cheight - marginX*2;

var svg1 = d3.select("#chrome").append("svg")
        .attr("width", cwidth)
        .attr("height", cheight)
  // graph range
        .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate("+ [marginX, marginX] +")")
  // plot area
  .append("g")
        .datum([width/3, height/2])
 .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate("+ d +")";
    });

var yGroup1 = svg1.append("g")
 .attr("class", "yGroups")
 .attr("id", "yGroup1")

//MAKE BASE LINES
var xRange = width/3,
 leftLine = yGroup1.append("line")
 .attr("class", "baseLines")
 .attr("id", "baseLine1")
 .attr({"x2": xRange});

//MAKE LINE LABELS
yGroup1.append("text")
 .attr("class", "lineLabels")
 .attr("id", "lineLabel1")
 .text(0)
 .attr("dx", "-1em")
 .attr("dy", "0.35em");

//MAKE BARS
var barWidth = 40;
var barHeight = 50;
var data = [{
            "id": "cBarTop", 
            "x": xRange*0.25, 
            "y": -barHeight,
      stroke: "none"
        },{
            "id": "cBarBot",
            "x": xRange / 2,
            "y": 0,
            stroke: "none"
        }]
    var cBar = svg1.selectAll("rect").data(data);
    cBar.enter().append("rect");
    cBar.attr({
            "class": "bars", 
            "id": attr("id"), 
            "x":attr("x"), 
            "width": barWidth, 
            "y": attr("y"), 
            "height": barHeight,
         stroke: attr("stroke")
        });

function attr(a){
    // set up a closure on a
 return function(d){return d[a]};
}

/*********************************
   ANIMATIONS
*********************************/
var aniDuration = 700;
var aniEase = "linear";

var leftButton = d3.select("#moveLeft");
var rightButton = d3.select("#moveRight");
leftButton.on("click", move(-xRange/2));
rightButton.on("click", move(xRange/2));

function move(yMove) {
 "use strict";
    // make a closure on yMove
 return function(){
        svg1.transition("linesUp")
            .duration(aniDuration)
            .ease(aniEase)
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
             var t = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr("transform")).translate;
                return "translate("+ [t[0] + yMove, t[1]] +")";
            });
    }
}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
#chrome {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 width: 640px;
 height: 150px;
 background: skyblue;
}

.baseLines {
 stroke: black;
 stroke-width: 5;
}

.bars {
 fill: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<button id="moveLeft">Move Left</button>
<button id="moveRight">Move Right</button>
    Chrome
<div id="chrome"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'm still in the process of making changes accommodate for the new group transitioning method, but overall it seems like it should work out beautifully.
Sorry about the late response, I thought I'd get an email if there was a response to this post, but I didn't and spent a lot of time doing stuff that wasn't working yesterday.
As for the architecture changes, some of doesn't seem clear to me at the moment, but I'll definitely play around with it once I get this done.  Another thanks for the additional help.